# VBA connecting to Snowflake generates error

Tags: vba, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to have a VBA script connect to Snowflake. I know my clients will ask about this, they will need to integrate the new Snowflake environment to their current monthly process, sadly part of it is built in VBA.

The authentication is done through Azure AD.I set the ODBC correctly with the externalbrowser parameter and it works fine in Excel when adding external data using the ODBC or using this ODBC with any other tool like Power BI.

In a VBA macro, I have the following code:

```
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "DSN=Snow_ODBC_BROWSER;"
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

I get the error :
*[Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL
https://.snowflakecomputing.com:failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perfrom() failed) - code=60 msg = 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.*

Some quick research talked about firewall certificate but I'm trying this from my home, no firewall.

Anyone has seen this? Any help would be great.

Thanks

JFS.

Comment: Your URL https://.snowflakecomputing.com/ is incorrect, it is missing your account

Comment: If it's not a networking issue (proxy, firewall, etc.), then possibly your Snowflake account URL is wrong (assuming you removed some of it for confidentiality but double-check it).  Your can also use the cURL command on it to see if there's any issues.   Just for reference, here is some example code from someone else who made VBA work so seems it can work:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008tOe5xSAC/is-it-possible-to-use-excel-vba-macro-to-readupdate-data-from-snowflake

Comment: Have a look at your DSN config. It looks like you're missing the account name config property

Comment: Of course I removed the account name for privacy confidentiality purposes. As I said, the DNS works fine directly in Excel or Power BI. The issue is when executed through VBA.